# Ought to do something

Tags: word-meaning

> If a TV show that one feels to be worth preserving would be canceled unless one took certain actions, then one **ought to** take those
>   actions.

What does *ought to* means? I thought it means "should", but when I replace it with "should", it sounds weird:

> If a TV show that one feels to be worth preserving would be canceled unless one took certain actions, then one **should** take those actions.

Comment: What's weird is the repeating of "one took/take actions", not the use of *should*.

Comment: The cited text is almost *facetiously* convoluted, so you certainly shouldn't think of it as an example of "good use of English". But syntactically it's fine with either of ***one ought to*** or ***one should***. It would even be possible to discard the infinitive marker ***to*** from the first version, but that would have been more likely a century or two ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two words are almost synonyms, but they have slightly different meanings. *ought* is often used in a moral context. It  roughly means "It would be morally/ethically correct for you to do X". *should*, on the other hand, usually means "it would be wise/prudent for you to do X". But the words can sometimes be used interchangeably.

From dictionary.com

> Ought
>
> 1. (used to express duty or moral obligation):

Vs.

> Should
>
> 1. Past tense of *shall* (meaning *will*)
> 2. (used to express a condition)
> 3. synonym to *ought* or *must*

Note that "ought" always implies duty or moral obligation, while *should* sometimes just implies what will *likely* happen. For example,

> "If he goes to bed early, he should rise early too."

Meaning : "If he goes to bed early, he is likely to rise early too."

Compared to

> "He ought to go to bed early so he can get his daughter to school on time."

Meaning: "He has a moral obligation/duty to go to bed early."

In your example, the use of *ought* implies that the writer believes that people have a *moral obligation* to help their favorite TV shows remain on the air (as weird as that sounds...) using *should* does not carry exactly the same connotation.